# List vs ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

```
List<EventHandler<E>> listeners = new List<EventHandler<E>>();
```

Why the line above fails with:

> Cannot instantiate the type `List<EventHandler<E>>`

But this one works:

```
ArrayList<EventHandler<E>> listeners = new ArrayList<EventHandler<E>>();
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The proper way is:

```
List<EventHandler<E>> listeners = new ArrayList<EventHandler<E>>();
```

- refer to an object by its interface (`List`)
- instantiate the object with its concrete type (`ArrayList`) (interfaces can't be instantiated)

Answer (score 15):

[`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface, you can't instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 6):

List is an interface and you can not create an instance of an interface

try

```
List<EventHandler<E>> listeners = new ArrayList<EventHandler<E>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `List<T>` is an [interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) so you can't instantiate it where as `ArrayList<T>` is a [concrete](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class which is an implementation of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

List is only an Interface which is implemented by ArrayList

see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 1):

List cannot be instantiated, as it's just an interface.

However, you potentially have another problem as well.

Do you really have a class called 'E'? If you do, well, you shouldn't without a very good reason.

Single letters such as E and T are pretty much exclusively used to denote a generic type parameter. Read it as: "This is a general description of how to make a class or method, without any reference to any specific type - you can parameterize this class by any legal reference type".

So even classes like ArrayList`<`T`>` cannot be instantiated - because they are generic "recipes" for classes, not real concrete classes.

Comment: Presumably your context-free link was supposed to draw attention to SO having eaten the angle brackets around ArrayList-parameterized-by-T.