# Generic List initilaization to ArrayList

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List versus ArrayList as reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist-as-reference-type)

I read somewhere in StackOverflow that this:

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is the best practice for initialization of ArrayList. And that this:

```
ArrayList<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
```

should be avoided. Is this correct? If yes can someone explain why is it so?

Thanks,
EG

Comment: possible duplicate of [List versus ArrayList as reference type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist-as-reference-type), [What is a List vs. an ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867484), [Java List vs ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309093), [List vs ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726361) and [Return ArrayList or List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683044)

Comment: If you wanted to replace ArrayList with another List, how many places would you need to change/check it works correctly in each example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how most developers use `ArrayList` (myself included), and is a general tenet of polymorphism. You should use the highest class/interface in the class hierarchy that you can while still having all your functionality available.

Generally, this makes your code more flexible, and you can switch out implementations more easily since you know that programming with `List` as the type hasn't bound you to using any methods that are only on `ArrayList` and not available on, say, a `LinkedList`.

For example, if I did:

```
LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
String s = strings.pop();
```

`pop` is exclusive to `LinkedList`, so I can't just change it directly to an `ArrayList`. I'd have to also change my code:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = strings.remove(strings.size() - 1);
```

But if I had just used the interface, I would've never used `pop` in the first place, so I could've just changed `strings` to whatever implementation I wanted.

This is especially important when programming APIs. If your methods are publicly accessible and will be used by other developers, then you need to make sure that you aren't restricting what kind of lists your methods take unless you have a good reason for doing so, especially since *they* may have a good reason for *not* wanting to use `ArrayList`.

If you're doing nothing but iteration and adding/removing, you could even go up to `Collection`. Here you start to lose context though, since `List` tells you it may contain duplicates and is ordered manually. But if this isn't particularly important and you can use `Collection`, you can even replace the lists with implementations of `Set`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Cleared all my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, First one gives flexibility to change implementation later time with minimal changes on client.

Example, you can change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`, but client will be minimally affected if it uses interface methods.

```
List<String> tempList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called designing to interfaces. 
Your code will be flexible, if you define List as a parameter both ArrayList and LinkedList (or anything else implementing the interface List) can be used as underlying implementation.