# List & ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Hi，I am a beginner of Java, I was taught to use "ArrayList" in OO programming in the Java lecture, however, I came across "List" today and have no idea how to use it, so what the difference between ArrayList and List? And what the same attributes of them?

something like:

```
           List<...>list=new List<...>()
           ArrayList<...>list=new ArrayList<...>()
```

Comment: The two answers right now won't be of any help to OP, since if they hadn't seen List before, they probably don't know what an interface is, either. Post a link to a better resource, I'd say.

Comment: Your first line wouldn't compile.

Comment: i think you should take a look at this thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903145/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-arraylist

Answer (score 4):

`List` is an *interface*, whereas `ArrayList` is a concrete class that implements that interface

Answer (score 1):

`List` is an interface.

`ArrayList` is a class that implements `List`.

You can't instantiate an interface, you have to instantiate one of classes which implements it.

Comment: Thanks mabbas, does it mean I can instantiate ArrayList without creating class, for example, I can use it in main() method directly, but I cannot do the same thing with List?

Comment: @peiwang You just need to import the package it's included in. That is `java.util`.

Comment: @peiwang I am not sure i understand your question, but to be able to use `ArrayList` in `main` method or any other method, you still need to create an instance of this class. Ex: `List<...> theList = new ArrayList<...>();`

Comment: @mabbas, thanks for the reply, so, List<...>theList=new ArrayList<...>(); and ArrayList<...>theList=new ArrayList<...>();have the same functions to store the content, right?

Comment: Yes but as @stefanoSanfilippo said, using `List` as a type for `theList` reduces the effort if someday you want to replace ArrayList with another class that implements `List`. So it is rather a good practice to refer to objects by their interfaces. I recommend you to take a look on this post http://jtechies.blogspot.fr/2012/07/item-52-refer-to-objects-by-their.html

Answer (score 0):

`List` is an interface, essentially providing a list of operations (add, remove, get...), but no implementation (you cannot do `new List`). There are several classes implementing `List` interface, including `ArrayList` (using, as said, an array as internal container) and, for instance, `LinkedList`. You can instantiate these, instead, and write:

```
List<ElementType> myList = new ArrayList<ElementType>();
```

Using `List` as a type for `myList` reduces the effort if you want to replace `ArrayList` with `LinkedList`:

```
List<ElementType> myList = new LinkedList<ElementType>();
```

(immagine, instead, if you had to replace `ArrayList` with `LinkedList` in several places, instead). Additionally, you will hide the actual implementation lying behind, so that other programmers don't make tricky assumptions on how the `List` might behave.

Answer (score 0):

`List` defines the basic contract that is expected that implementations would provide.  `ArrayList` is a implementation of this contract that is backed by a dynamic array.

The great thing about this idea is, if you have a method that needs access to some kind of `List`, you can simply ask that callers pass you any implementation of `List`, meaning you don't need to know or care how the `List` is actually implemented, only that it will provide the contract described by `List`

You can't create an instance of `List` directly, you need to use one of the implementations, like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`...

For example...

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>(25);
List<String> anotherListOfStrings = new LinkedList<String>();
```