# Remove odd elements from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static List<Integer> removeOddNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) { throw new Error(); }
        List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i : list) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) { toRemove.add(i); }
        }
        list.removeAll(toRemove);
        return list;
}
```

I'm trying to remove all odd elements from an ArrayList and then returning that ArrayList.

I'm getting an error pointing to List Integer in this first line

**Test:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(arrayList, 3, 5, 6, 24, 7, 9, 1, 8, 28, 11);
ArrayList<Integer> result = removeOddNumbers(arrayList);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Result:**

```
[6, 24, 8, 28]
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: You can use another list to store the element you want to keep or iterate backwards.

Comment: Can you please add the code where you call `removeOddNumbers`?

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can just use [Collection::removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) :

```
list.removeIf(i -> i % 2 != 0);
```

---

The full method should look like this :

```
public static List<Integer> removeOddNumbers(List<Integer> list) {
    list.removeIf(i -> i % 2 != 0);
    return list;
}
```

---

**Example**

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4));
list.removeIf(i -> i % 2 != 0);
System.out.println(removeOddNumbers(list));
```

**Outputs**

```
[2, 6, 4]
```

Comment: where would I use this?

Comment: what did you mean **where would I use this?**

Comment: I think he has another problem. The code should mainly work - even if it's not the easiest way.

Comment: getting a cannot find symbol error on List <Integer>

Comment: @qwert123 use `List<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`, check my edit

Comment: what did you mean @sarkasronie?

Comment: If you give him a hint, what his problem was, you'll get +1 from me. Because his problem wasn't the algorithm of removing odd numbers.

Comment: @sarkasronie the OP seems he call his method using `List<Integer> list` and `List<Integer> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: @qwert123 up to you, to understand more take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903145/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-arraylist

Answer (score 4):

You should go for Iterator to remove items from List. That would save the usage of a temporary list where you store odd elements.

```
public static List<Integer> removeOddNumbers(List<Integer> arrayList) {
    Iterator<Integer> itr = arrayList .iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        int x = (Integer)itr.next();
        if (x % 2 != 0) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    } 
    return arrayList;
}
```

OR

You can go for a lot easier code with Java8.

Answer (score 1):

lambda way :

```
public static List<Integer> filter(List<Integer> numberList) {
    return numberList.stream()
        .filter(number -> number % 2 != 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You should call this method with this :

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3, 5, 6, 24, 7, 9, 1, 8, 28, 11);
List<Integer> result = removeOddNumbers(numbers);
System.out.println(result);
```

The problem is that the returning type of the method is `List<Integer>` but your code expect an `ArrayList` the solution is to simply use the generic class `List` or if you want use your code it should be like this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(arrayList, 3, 5, 6, 24, 7, 9, 1, 8, 28, 11);
List<Integer> result = removeOddNumbers(arrayList);
System.out.println(result);
```

**N.B** The method posted by @YCF_L edit the list that you pass by the parameter, my method instead create a new list leaving the original list untouched

Comment: Indeed. getting a cannot find symbol error on List <Integer> as well

Comment: @qwert123 Post the full class, this is probably a syntax error

Comment: Not given a class, but posted the test

Comment: @qwert123 fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can use Iterator.remove()
List arr = new ArrayList();
        arr .add(10);
        arr .add(20);
        arr .add(30);
        arr .add(1);
        arr .add(2);

        // Remove odd elements
        // Iterator.remove()
        Iterator itr = arr .iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            int x = (Integer)itr.next();
            if (x % 2 != 0)
                itr.remove();
        } 
        System.out.println("Modified ArrayList : "                                     + arr);
```